# Prove that y-intercept of polynomial is the product of its roots

Tags: polynomials, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Please prove that, if the polynomial $p(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ has
>   roots $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$, then $d = a \times x_1 \times x_2 \times
> x_3$

My attempt:

Since $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ are roots of $p(x)$, then $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3) = 0$.

Substitute $ 0 $ and $p(x) = 0$ into the polynomial. Hence we obtain:

$$
d = (0 - x_1)(0-x_2)(0-x_3) = -a(-x_1)(-x_2)(-x_3) = 0
$$
Hence, the condition for d is proven.

The last statement of the proof looks wrong to me. I can't think of any other way to complete this proof. Could someone please advise me whether my proof is sound or not?

Comment: "Since $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are roots of $p(x)$, then $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)=0$." I think this is where you went wrong. You want to say that $p(x)$ can be written as $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$, possibly times a constant. (And that constant would have to be $a$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=p(x)$, so if $(0,y_i)$ is the $y$-intercept, then $y_i = p(0) = d$. Since $p(x) = a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$, $p(0)=-ax_1x_2x_3$, so $d=-ax_1x_2x_3$.

Note that the statement you are trying to prove is in fact incorrect. It is true for polynomials of even degree, while a minus sign shows up in front for polynomials of odd degree.

Ex: $p(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3) = x^3-6x^2+11x-6$, with $d=1\times-1\times-2\times-3 = -6$.

Comment: Hmm. I am not sure how you got $p(x)=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$. If $x_1,x_2$ and $x_3$ are roots, then $p(x)=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$ right?

Comment: I'll use a quadratic as an example, $p(x) = 2x^2-8$. Since $p(2) = 0$ and $p(-2) = 0$, $2$ and $-2$ are the roots of $p$. However, $(x-2)(x+2) = x^2-4$, while $2(x-2)(x+2) = 2x^2-8$.